# CSS float:left causes thumbnails to align diagonal to each other...>.<

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm receiving this weird problem when updating the structure of my site.

Site URL is http://nailian.ca.

I have many many  per page, but when I give them a

thumbnail {float:left; width:150px; height:200px; margin:6px;}

they start to align diagonal to each other on my front page.

I know it has something to do with other parts of the CSS since I can do this trick with no problem on an online practice board.

But why on my site it acts sooo moody!!??

Comment: Try removing the padding-bottom in 
.hentry {padding-bottom : 1.62em}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial problem is that your html structure goes like this:

[image: http://img143.imageshack.us/img143/3696/thumbubc.jpg]

1. `.thumbnails` are the containers for your images.
2. Which means you have post container in between every image for some
   reason.
3. You should get the post's away from between or put all the images
   inside one post.

( note that the post containers are empty. )

Answer (score 1):

change `.hentry, .no-results{}` by adding `float: right;`

html parts like

```
 <article id="post-708" class="post-708 post type-post status-publish format-standard     hentry category-uncategorized">       
   <header class="entry-header">                                           
     <!-- .entry-meta -->                                                
   </header>
   <!-- .entry-header -->           
 </article>
```

are inbetween the thumb image html and causing the issue, adding float to them gives them `0` width, solving the issue (it aint a pretty fix tough)

Answer (score 0):

After every .thumbnail you have an ARTICLE tag, that messes up the CSS, i.e. the thumbnails are not in container, but there are as many articles as there are thumbnails. So either remove the articles from the equation or use Benjamin’s solution.